# Como usar 2 temas Wordpress no mesmo blog?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Tenho um tema que quero usar na página inicial e tenho outro que quero usar para os posts.

É possível fazer isso? Se sim, como?

Comment: Está o usando o wordpress como mult-site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim é possível a utilização de mais de um tema na instalação do wordpress, mas para isso é necessário a utilização de `plugins` para essa finalidade, mas vale destacar que o uso de `multi-tema` pode impactar e muito na performance do site, o recomendável é a utilização de um `plugin` de performance e arquivos minimizados dos css e js.

Para utilizar siga os passos abaixo:

1. Faça backup dos dados e banco de dados antes de iniciar
2. Instale o [W3 Total Cache](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) ou [WP Super Cache](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/), para deixar o ambiente mais performático.
3. Instale os temas desejados (pule está etapa se o mesmo já foi feito)
4. Agora instale o plugin [Jonradio multiple themes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/) é ele que será responsável por controlar onde cada tema deve ser inserido. Caso queria pode visitar o site do desenvolvedor do plugin e obter respostas do forum deles também aqui [zatzlabs](http://zatzlabs.com/project/multiple-themes/).

*Antes de grandes aterações no wordpress não se esqueça de fazer o bkp de todos os dados e do banco de dados.